# com.netaporter.uri.Uri alternative for Scala 2.13?

Tags: scala

I was using netaporter [uri](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netaporter/scala-uri) and it was supported until Scala 2.12. But doesn't seem to be supported in Scala 2.13. Is there any alternative that can be used in Scala 2.13?
[image]

This is the functionality I am trying to recreate:

```scala
 import com.netaporter.uri.Uri
 val uri: Try[Uri] = Try(Uri.parse(record.url))
 val addressForCall = uri.flatMap(address => Try(address.withHost(address.host.get)))
```

Comment: Generally you'd use the Uri type of the http library you're using, like http4s Uri, etc

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative to the given [package](https://github.com/lemonlabsuk/scala-uri) for scala 2.13+.

Instead of `Uri`, we need to use `Url`.

`.host` becomes `.hostOption`

`.address` becomes `.addressOption`